# Retrieve an individual hash table element in redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, redis

I would like to have access to an individual hash table element and its corresponding value i.e. 'node' 'express'

How could I do this?

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(); //creates a new client

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
});

client.hmset('frameworks', {
    'javascript': 'AngularJS',
    'css': 'Bootstrap',
    'node': 'Express'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use client.hget('frameworks','node')

Answer (score 1):

client.js

> var redis = require('redis'); var client = redis.createClient();
>
> var field = 'css'; 
>   client.hget('frameworks',field, function(err,result) {
>           console.log( field + ' : ' + result) });

The Result is:
css : Bootstrap